# Saving canvas image to server

Tags: php, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have extracted data from a database to create an HTML table which I want to be able to save as a PNG on the server.

When I save the PNG to the server using PHP, it is blank.

I have created static code (i.e. not from database) to illustrate my example.

If I manually right click on the image, and SAVE AS then the image is saved correctly, it is only when I try to automate it that the image is blank. I have tried in both Chrome and Firefox, both with the same results.

If anyone can help me correct whatever I am doing wrong, I would be grateful. Thank you.

I am using:

- PHP 7.3.4
- jQuery 3.4.1
- Chrome 76.0.3809.100
- Firefox 68.01

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="invoicetable">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <style>
        body        {font-family: courier new; font-size: 13px; }
        td      {padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; }
        .headerTD   {font-weight: bold; }
        .w60        {width: 60px; }
        .w80        {width: 80px; }
        .w100       {width: 100px; }
        .w120       {width: 120px; }
        .w160       {width: 160px; }
            </style>

<table class='' border='01' style='border-collapse: collapse; font-size: 14px; font-family: trebuchet ms; '><tr><td class='headerTD w100'>Date</td><td class='headerTD w60'>Type</td><td class='headerTD w160'>Detail</td><td class='headerTD w120'>Username</td><td class='headerTD w100'>Line</td><td class='headerTD w100'>Start Date</td><td class='headerTD w100'>End Date</td><td class='headerTD w80'>Subtotal</td></tr><tr><td>23/07/2019</td><td>Credit</td><td>Business Fibre 1</td><td>abc@def.com</td><td>011122223333</td><td>23/07/2019</td><td>21/08/2019</td><td>&pound; <div style='float: right'>-7.74</div></td></tr><tr><td>04/08/2019</td><td>Charge</td><td>Business Fibre 1</td><td>ghi@jkl.com</td><td>01234567890</td><td>04/08/2019</td><td>03/09/2019</td><td>&pound; <div style='float: right'>22.50</div></td></tr><tr><td>04/08/2019</td><td>Charge</td><td>Line Rental</td><td></td><td>01234567890</td><td>04/08/2019</td><td>03/09/2019</td><td>&pound; <div style='float: right'>15.66</div></td></tr><tr><td>04/08/2019</td><td>Charge</td><td>Line Rental</td><td></td><td>01234567890</td><td>04/07/2019</td><td>03/08/2019</td><td>&pound; <div style='float: right'>0.00</div></td></tr><tr><td colspan='7'></td><td>&pound; <div style='float: right'>30.42</div></td></tr></table>

        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="930" height="150"></canvas>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var imgW = 930;
            var imgH = 150;
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, imgW, imgH);

            var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='" + imgW + "' height='" + imgH + "'>" + "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" + $("#invoicetable").html() + "</foreignObject>" + "</svg>";
            var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
            var img = new Image();
            var svg = new Blob([data], {
                type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
            });
            var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
            img.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            };
            img.src = url;

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            var pngData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            $.post("savepng.php", {
                pngData: pngData
            }, function(data) {});

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**savepng.php**

```
<?php
$aaa = explode(",", $_POST['pngData']);
file_put_contents("invoicedata.png", base64_decode($aaa[1]));
?>
```

This is the expected image output:
[image: The expected image output]

Comment: `toDataURL` prepends the following `data:image/png;base64,`. You will need to remove this before decoding on the server.

Comment: @LeeTaylor He is removing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has three problems:

1. You are trying to save the image before you even draw your SVG image onto the canvas.
   Save the image inside the `onload` callback.
2. Seems you took the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39148582) question without fixing the problem, so you get an error about a tainted canvas when you call `toDataURL`.
3. There seems to be a problem rendering the pound sign, if you use the fix from the previous problem. This seem to be a problem with the encoding and the fix is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26603875).

To fix those issues use this code:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var pngData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    $.post("savepng.php", {
        pngData: pngData
    }, function(data) {});
};
function buildSvgImageUrl(svg) {
    var b64 = window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg)));
    return "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + b64;
}
img.src = buildSvgImageUrl(data);
```

Comment: Thank you so much gre_gor, I had indeed not added the correction. All is working now. Thanks again :-)